# Require component children to be of certain type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following component:

```
interface OwnProps {
  children: React.ReactElement<any>[];
}

export class ActionMenuRenderer extends React.Component<OwnProps> {
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const actions = React.Children.toArray(children) as React.ReactElement<any>[];

    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
<ActionMenuRenderer>
  <button type="button">View</button>
  <button type="button">Edit</button>
  <button type="button">Delete</button>
</ActionMenuRenderer>
```

I would like to require that children of `ActionMenuRenderer` be either `<a>`s or `<button>`s.  I tried making the following change, but I'm not seeing a compiling error in my IDE:

```
interface OwnProps {
  children: React.ReactElement<HTMLButtonElement | HTMLAnchorElement>[];
}
```

How can I require component children to be of a certain type?

Comment: So if you change the children to e.g `span`, you will not get a compilation error?

Comment: @Tholle Correct.

Comment: This is not currently possible in Typescript due to all React children types being expanded to JSX.Element: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699

Comment: @y2bd: Wow.  Thanks for the link.  Subscribed!

Comment: @y2bd - Unsatisfying as it is, that's an *answer*. I suggest posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible in Typescript (as of 3.2). Typescript will generate all React components as the general JSX.Element type, which will unfortunately satisfy any specific child type you might try to restrict instead.

Source:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699